# Is it grammatically correct to use "baby" as a proper noun

Tags: grammar, proper-nouns

A lot of baby books and products use the word *baby* as you would a proper noun.

For example "when lying *baby* down in the cot" instead of "when lying *your baby* down in the cot". Another example from a shampoo bottle "proven to help *baby* sleep better". Books about child raising don't say "when teaching *child* good manners".

Where did this practice arise and is it valid?

Comment: "Have you seen junior's grades?" (line from Van Halen lyrics, *Cradle Will Rock*). Interesting how baby and junior can be treated this way but not some other words like child.

Comment: I find this most curious – how in the world is *shampoo* proven to help babies *sleep* better?

Comment: @René: worst reason ever. Peeving is expressly off-topic on this site.

Comment: One cannot **lie a baby down*; one can only *lay a baby down*.  The object is baby, so it must be a transitive verb; *to lie* is intransitive, and wrong here.

Comment: @tchrist: I won't lie to you – I never wanted to get that wrong, which is why I always _stuck_ (or _plopped_) my babies in the crib.

Comment: I'm second eldest of five siblings. We were still calling the youngest "Baby" until she was five. We stopped calling her "**the** Baby" when she started talking (about 18 months), but we didn't abandon "Baby" until a few months before she started school (when it dawned on us that what we thought of as her "name" might be a bit awkward there). She's over 50 now, but me and my elder brother still sometimes refer to her as "Our Kid" even though we're Southerners, and that's normally a Midlands/Northern term.

Comment: No, proper nouns have to be capitalized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't hear "when teaching child good manners," but we certainly hear things like "when teaching junior good manners"— as well as

> why Johnny can't read
>
> tell teacher what you saw
>
> father knows best
>
> when precious snowflake gets out into the real world

and so on. The *baby* (like *junior*, et al) is here an archetype, for which you may substitute any particular instance, or all instances.

Not every noun is used this way, as it must be clear we are not speaking of a specific individual but of a generic example. Mr. Burns clearly isn't [meeting an actual uncle](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Burns_Verkaufen_der_Kraftwerk) when he says he wants to

> … look Uncle Fritz square in the monocle and say *Nein!*

Comment: Is Uncle Fritz a proper noun? Also see edited question.

Comment: The question is whether one can treat people as objects, isn't it? "Tell teacher what you saw" is not very far removed grammatically from "Twist lid to remove". Using "teacher", "father", "baby" in this way would suggest a capital letter, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Andrew Leach. It surely would, but I've been reading "The Help" recently and there's plenty of "baby" used this way. I took it as an attempt to render the speech of coloured people.

Comment: @nevster It is a proper noun in the sense that it is a name and used to represent a unique concept; however, it does not refer to any particular individual. Writers may refer to *Joe Sixpack* or *John Q. Public* in the same way, referring to the "common man," though Mr. Burns prefers formulations like *Eddie Punchclock*, *Sally Housecoat*, and *Joey Lunchpail*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Perhaps it is a matter of which style guide one is following, but I rarely see them captalized unless it is a "named character" as in the examples above.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that "Johnny" is indefinite, not necessarily referring to someone actually with that name.

Answer (score 7):

I think in this usage, 'baby' is being used as a noun naming a member of the family, in the same way as 'mother' or 'father'. In the same way that we say "This  is for mother/father" without any articles or possessives, we could say "This is for baby".

Having said that, I have to say that I find it quite maudlin.

Answer (score 3):

I can see why such magazines would want to avoid the use of *your* – after all, it might not be the reader's baby.  (The reader could be a grandparent, or unrelated caregiver).  On the other hand, if most of the readers *are* the baby's parents, using an article such as *a* or *the* might read very impersonal.  Maybe this is a way to settle the quandary?

By the way, I'm with you – it reads like annoying baby talk, or [IDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_talk), although I don't think it's designed to read that way.

Comment: Have you noticed how freaked parents get if you **don't** talk to their baby in baby talk? I mean, if they don't want you to try and discuss the latest LHC results with their baby - why do they stick it in your face?

Answer (score -3):

"Baby" is not a proper noun, unless used as an actual name. "Baby" should be referred to using an article or prepositional verb.

Comment: Not necessarily at all times. The usage is widely recognized.